# detect touch from back thread or service

Tags: android, service, click, touch

1- Is it possible in android to detect touch/click on screen or on app with the help of service?

2- Actually i want to detect touch event on screen with the help of service and when my service listen that event a signal send a to my app...
I am googling alot but no luck e.g [Creating a system overlay window (always on top)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4481226/creating-a-system-overlay-always-on-top-button-in-android) but i don't want to create any visible view on screen... thanx for any help

Answer (score 0):

No you can't detect any UI event in a service since it does not have any access to anywhere, even if your application is running you service only can access if you pass your window manually through an activity to the service and the do some process on it and that can't be done when your application is not running.